# Generate Iron Python UnitTest results

Tags: python, unit-testing, ironpython, cruisecontrol.net

I currently have several iron python modules, each with a class that implements unittest.TestCase.

I'm running the test classes through a .bat file as such:

```
@set IRONPYTHONPATH=..\TestProject\bin;
@ipy -m unittest -v TestClass1 TestClass2
```

Those lines run TestClass1 and TestClass2 and all of their internal tests, and the result gets output to the console.

What I need now is to be able to integrate this testing module into a Cruise Control process (which calls to MSBuild).  If a test fails, Cruise Control needs to be able to read the error, so I was thinking maybe I could somehow generate an xml file with the results.  So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to generate a results file from the IronPython tests so it can be fed later into Cruise Control?
2. Is calling the test classes from a command line a bad design (aka would it limit the result reporting capabilities from ironPython?)

Comment: In CPython the unittest module is pretty "modular" and you can exchange the "output" part with your own. Maybe that works for IronPython too?

Answer (score 0):

[unittest-xml-reporting](https://github.com/danielfm/unittest-xml-reporting) should give you what you want. I don't know if it works on IronPython, though.

Answer (score 0):

you could set the output of the console to a file like this:

```
     System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("c:\\temp\\ipy.log", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
       engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(fs, Encoding.ASCII);
```